# d3 multiple circles per tick from grouped data array

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to learn d3 very quickly and I'm getting pretty stuck on selection and joining.

I want to be able to draw an axis with dots for each member of an array. Some of the array members have the same x value, but I still want to see as many dots as there are with that value. My array (in React with useState) looks like so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(
    [
      {x: 2020, colour: "purple", y1: 0.001, y2: 0.63},
      {x: 2027, colour: "red", y1: 0.003, y2: 0.84},
      {x: 2031, colour: "yellow", y1: 0.024, y2: 0.56},
      {x: 2031, colour: "green", y1: 0.054, y2: 0.22},
      {x: 2040, colour: "blue", y1: 0.062, y2: 0.15},
      {x: 2050, colour: "orange", y1: 0.062, y2: 0.15}
    ]
);
```

You can see there are two values for 2031 and I want to draw a yellow dot, then a purple dot below, at the x axis tick labelled "2031".

So I group my data with this reduce function (purloined from SO):

```
const dot = data.reduce(
    (r, v, _, __, k = v.x) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r),
    {}
);
```

...which produces this:

```
{ 2020: [{x: 2020, colour: "purple", y1: 0.001, y2: 0.63}],
  2027: [...] }
```

I initiate my x axis and create a placeholder for it:

```
const g = d3.axisBottom( scX ).tickValues(
      data.map(d => {
        return d.x 
      })
    )

svg.append( "g" )
    .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 25 + "," + pxY/2 + ")")
    .call( g )
    .selectAll(".tick")
```

And then I want to call my dot variable and iterate over the nested arrays:

```
svg
    .selectAll(".tick")
    .call( dot )
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", dot.colour)
```

What I would like this to do is draw a circle for every one of the nested arrays, with a fill the colour named in that array - this does not work?

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to group your data. You can just see `data` as an array, where every element will correspond to one circle. Multiple circles can exist with the same `x`-value, nothing enforces that they can't.

There is also no need to set the axis ticks like that, d3 will most likely do everything for you. `d3-axis` is an absolute convenience - you're meant to tweak the defaults, not build everything from scratch here.

You need to learn about [data joins](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data), since you apparently also don't know that you can access the data of an element using `function(d, i) { ... }` or `(d, i) => ...` to set the colour that way.

```js
const data = [{
    x: 2020,
    colour: "purple",
    y1: 0.001,
    y2: 0.63
  },
  {
    x: 2027,
    colour: "red",
    y1: 0.003,
    y2: 0.84
  },
  {
    x: 2031,
    colour: "yellow",
    y1: 0.024,
    y2: 0.56
  },
  {
    x: 2031,
    colour: "green",
    y1: 0.054,
    y2: 0.22
  },
  {
    x: 2040,
    colour: "blue",
    y1: 0.062,
    y2: 0.15
  },
  {
    x: 2050,
    colour: "orange",
    y1: 0.062,
    y2: 0.15
  }
];

const width = 600,
  height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x))
  .range([50, 550]);

const y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y1))
  .range([275, 25]);

const y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y2))
  .range([3, 10]);

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("fill", d => d.colour)
  .attr("cx", d => x(d.x))
  .attr("cy", d => y1(d.y1))
  .attr("r", d => y2(d.y2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```